# How to pass an NSString to a UILabel on a new ViewController with didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to send a string from my TableViewContoller to my LabelViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The string is the number of the row in my table. In LabelViewController.h I have my UILabel property called *rowNumberLabel.

In my TableViewController, I attempt to set the text of the label in didSelectRowAtIndexPath with the following code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    self.numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", self.rowNumber];
    LabelViewController *labelViewController = [[LabelViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The row number is %@", self.numberString);
    labelViewController.rowNumberLabel.text = self.numberString;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:labelViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I am very sure I am looking over something simple but I cannot figure out why the text of the label is not setting when I push labelViewController. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `rowNumberLabel` isn't connected right after initializing the `LabelViewController`.

- Create a property in `LabelViewController` and assign `numberString` to that property.
- In `LabelViewController` assign the property to the label in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Of course, such an easy fix I was overlooking! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In TableViewcontroller

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    self.numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", self.rowNumber];
    LabelViewController *labelViewController = [[LabelViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The row number is %@", self.numberString);
    labelViewController.labelstring = self.numberString;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:labelViewController animated:YES];
}
```

In LabelViewController
.h File

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString * labelstring;
```

.m File

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.rowNumberLabel.text = labelstring;

}
```